# Can a target's prerequisite without build rule have generated transitive prerequisites?

Tags: makefile, dependencies, gnu-make

I have the following `Makefile`:

```
.PHONY: all

all: foo qux

foo: bar
    cp bar foo

qux: bar
    cp bar qux

-include bar.d

clean:
    rm -f foo qux
```

which includes a generated `bar.d` file:

```
bar: baz
```

I'd like to be able to run the rules for `foo` and `qux` whenever `bar` **or `baz`** is changed.

Without surprise, it works well when I change `bar`, but when I change `baz`, I get the following message:

```
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
```

If I change the contents of `bar.d` to the following, I get the expected behaviour:

```
foo: baz

qux: baz
```

But it would be easier for me not to have to duplicate the `$x: baz` rule for every target that depends on `bar`.

Is there a solution that does not involves changing `baz.d`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no recipe for `bar`, Make's actions are correct; yes, `baz` has changed, but there is no way to bring `bar` up to date, therefore no point in rebuilding the targets that depend on `bar`.

You can get the behavior you want by adding an "update" recipe to the rule:

```
bar: baz
    @touch $@
```